# jQuery: mouseenter/mouseleave even stop propagation

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave, stoppropagation

I'm using mouseenter and mouseleave events in jquery on an unordered list's `<li>` to show some image when the mouse goes over them. Here's what that list typically looks like:

```
<ul class="myTree">
    <li class="treeItem" catid="1" catname="Category 1">
        <img src="img/fleche_hori.png" class="expandImage"/>
        Category 1
        <img src="img/cross.png" class="hidden removecategory"/>
        <ul>
            <li class="treeItem" catid="2" catname="Subcategory 1 1">
                <img src="img/spacer.gif" class="expandImage"/>
                Subcategory 1 1
                <img src="img/cross.png" class="hidden removecategory"/>
            </li>
            <li class="treeItem" catid="3" catname="Subcategory 1 2">
                <img src="img/spacer.gif" class="expandImage"/>
                Subcategory 1 2
                <img src="img/cross.png" class="hidden removecategory"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeItem" catid="4" catname="Category 2">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

*NOTE: I know it can be hard to read but I tried my best to make it as readable as possible.*

So as you can see it's merely a tree used for an expand/collapse tree, each item being marked with class "treeItem". I need this class to stay and as it's a common class shared by all these items that need to show an image when mouse goes over them, I decided to bind my event handler to it.

The image that needs to be showed/hidden on mouseenter/mouseleave is the second of each item (the one with src="img/cross.png"). I managed to that quite easily with this script:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".treeItem", function (e) {
    //e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children(".removecategory").show();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".treeItem", function (e) {
    //e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children(".removecategory").hide();
});
```

My problem though is that when an item is expanded (i.e. "Category 1" is expanded and "Subcategory 1 1" and "Subcategory 1 2" are now shown) and I hover any of the sub-categories with my mouse, these subcategories' images will be shown as asked but the parent category's (i.e. "Category 1") image won't hide as I'm still hovering it as well...

I tried using e.stopPropagation(); but it didn't do anything better..

Anyone knows a way to go around this and sort of trigger mouseleave on an element when I'm hovering some of its content ?

You can check http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/#example-0 and especially the demo below the code block to see what I mean. Typically (on the right side of the demo) I would like that blue container's mouseleave event is triggered when mouse enters yellow container.

*I hope my question is clear because it was hard to explain...*

---

**EDIT**:

I found a way modifying my mouseenter event handler to this:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".treeItem", function (e) {
    $('.removecategory').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(this).children(".removecategory").show();
});
```

but that isn't perfect as I need to leave the entire parent item (i.e. "Category 1" item) and re-enter it to have the image shown again after hovering subitems.

If anyone has a better way please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add span to each category and subcategory:

```
<ul class="myTree">
    <li class="treeItem" catid="1" catname="Category 1">
        <img src="img/fleche_hori.png" class="expandImage"/>
        <span class="Item">Category 1</span>
        <img src="http://www.pokerland-il.com/images/smilies/smile.png" class="hidden removecategory"/>
        <ul>
            <li class="treeItem" catid="2" catname="Subcategory 1 1">
                <img src="" class="expandImage"/>
                <span class="Item">Subcategory 1 1</span>
                <img src="http://www.pokerland-il.com/images/smilies/smile.png" class="hidden removecategory"/>
            </li>
            <li class="treeItem" catid="3" catname="Subcategory 1 2">
                <img src="img/spacer.gif" class="expandImage"/>
                <span class="Item">Subcategory 1 2</span>
                <img src="http://www.pokerland-il.com/images/smilies/smile.png" class="hidden removecategory"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeItem" catid="4" catname="Category 2">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>​
```

change your JS to this:

```
$('.Item').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next(".removecategory").show();
});

$('.Item').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next(".removecategory").hide();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBwyZ/3/

Comment: hmm I don't like to duplicate code but if no one can give a better answer I'll have to go with this. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: you can give a different class only to the first li - the Category one

Comment: Btw, I just tried it. And it just doesn't work. It gives the same result and its quite obvious why ^^ so that isn't the way to go.

Comment: thank you :) that works fine! make it a proper answer so I can accept that =)

Comment: by the way kleinohad I had to insert my image into the span because as the event was on the span the image would just disappear before my mouse could reach it ;) changing the code a bit to $(this).children(".removecategory").hide(); instead of next() :) Thank you ;)